# Problema al renderizar con efecto ( useEffect ) REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Tengo un **conjunto de items** pintados, puedo seleccionar varios ítems para borrarlos y con un botón ejecuto el borrado. Cuando elimino pretendo forzar un renderizado con una constante que su valor inicial esta en `false`. El problema es que no me renderiza correctamente.

Tal y como lo tengo, cuando se hace un borrado de una selección este cambia a true forzando un renderizado y así en el cliente actualiza el resultado. Pero en lugar de ese resultado me salta un error de servidor.

Y no comprendo por que me pasa eso o como podría solucionarlo...

Si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar el error lo agradecería

**Menu.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { loadMenu, deletingItem } from '../service/service';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';

function Menu(){

    const[menu,setMenu] = useState([]);
    const[deleting,setDeleting] = useState([]);
    const[refresh,setRefresh] = useState(false);

    function onLoadMenu (){
        loadMenu().then(m => {
            setMenu(m);
        })
    }

    function onSelected (id) {
        if(!deleting.includes(id)){
            setDeleting([...deleting,id]);
        }
    }

    function onDeleted(){
       deleting.map(del => deletingItem(del));
       setRefresh(true); //Fuerzo el refresh a true 
    }

    useEffect(() => { //Efecto de renderizado 
        onLoadMenu();
        setRefresh(false);
    },[refresh])

    return(
        <main>
             {menu.map(m => <MenuItem id={m.id} key={m.id} title={m.title} onSelected={onSelected} deleting={deleting.includes(m.id)}/>)}
             <button onClick={onDeleted}>Delete Selection</button>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

**MenuItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function MenuItem({id, title, onSelected, deleting}){
    return(
        <li onClick={() => onSelected(id)} className={deleting ? "selected" : "normal"}>{title}</li>
    );
}

export default MenuItem;
```

**Service.js**

```
export const url = 'http://localhost:3004/';

export const loadMenu = async() =>{
    const end = await fetch(url + 'menu');
    const json = end.json();
    return json;
}

export const deletingItem = async(id) => {
    const end = await fetch(url + 'menu/' + id, { method : 'DELETE'});
    const json = await end.json();
    return json;
}
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "menu" : [
        {"id" : 1, "title" : "Item 1"},
        {"id" : 2, "title" : "Item 2"},
        {"id" : 3, "title" : "Item 3"},
        {"id" : 4, "title" : "Item 4"},
        {"id" : 5, "title" : "Item 5"},
        {"id" : 6, "title" : "Item 6"},
        {"id" : 7, "title" : "Item 7"},
        {"id" : 8, "title" : "Item 8"},
        {"id" : 9, "title" : "Item 9"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: En Menu.js y dentro del `useEffect()`, ¿por qué estás haciendo el `setRefresh(false);`? No lo veo necesario porque ya inicializaste a `refresh` con el valor false. No sé si es ese el problema que produce tu error, pero creo que eso te va a re-renderizar el componente de forma innecesaria.

Comment: Esta inicializado en falso y cuando realizo el borrado de los ítems el valor cambia a true, esto fuerza el renderizado ya que lo paso como parámetro al efecto y posterior a la carga de datos onLoadMenu() lo devuelvo a su estado original. Pero no funciona como esperaba. Debería de hacer un borrado y una vez este eliminado del servidor acto seguido forzar un renderizado para que en cliente los datos se muestren actualizados.

Comment: Ah, ahora entiendo mejor tu idea. Pero aun así sigo pensando que es innecesario porque cuando intentas regresar a `refresh` a su valor original vas a volver a forzar el re-renderizado. Una recomendación para intentar hacer lo que pretendes que a mí me da mucho éxito, es setear el estado que fuerza el renderizado con `Math.random()`. Por ejemplo, `setRefresh(Math.random())`. Así cada vez que en tu caso llamas a `onDeleted()` vas a asignar un estado random que siempre va a cambiar y nunca es el mismo. Si intentas esa sugerencia, no te olvides de sacar el `setRefresh(false)` del `useEffect()`.

Comment: Vale, voy a poner en practica tu sugerencia y veo si con tu idea alcanzo la solución que busco gracias por ayudar !!

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de hacer la operación `write` al servidor, se hace el cambio de la bandera `refresh`, de tal forma que al devolver el componente otra vez, su valor sea `true`, aunque también puede ser necesario vaciar el UI state llamado `deleting` antes de devolver el componente nuevamente:

```
function onDeleted(){
     deleting.map(del => deletingItem(del));
     //hay que vaciar el estado ui deleting para cada re-render
     setDeleting([]); 
     //Fuerzo el refresh a true
     setRefresh(true); 
  }
```

Ahora, se puede intentar lo siguiente, se configura el `unmount` de `useEffect` para que se regrese la bandera `refresh` a su estado original `false` después de cada carga de datos:

```
useEffect(() => { //Efecto de renderizado 
      onLoadMenu();
      //setRefresh(false);
      //component unmount
      return ()=> setRefresh(false);
  },[refresh])
```

Finalmente, usando el dependency array se le indica a `useEffect` que debe correr el efecto, cada vez que su dependencia `refresh` cambie de valor. Es decir vamos cambiando el valor de la dependencia `refresh` de `false` a `true` y otra vez a `false` cada vez que se elimina un `item`.

#### Actualización

> Error 1 : GET localhost:3004/menu net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error 2 : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Yo intentaría completar la información del objeto `init` de `fetch` dentro de la función `deletingItem`:

```
const end = await fetch(url + 'menu/' + id, 
                  { method : 'DELETE', 
                    headers: {'Content-Type':  'application/json'}
                  });
```

[Casos comúnes fetch](https://cameronnokes.com/blog/4-common-mistakes-front-end-developers-make-when-using-fetch/)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Vale gracias voy a intentar la solucion con el unmount en el useEffect

Comment: Esa solución me parece más práctica que la mía. Es mejor práctica utilizar las funcionalidades propias de React a buscar soluciones personalizadas. Con el cambio de componentes de clases a los Hooks, yo perdí la costumbre de usar `component unmount`. Gracias por mostrar cómo utilizarlo con Hooks en este caso.

Comment: He incorporado tu solución pero me sigue reportando el mismo fallo en servidor pero gracias por la ayuda !! 
Error 1 : GET http://localhost:3004/menu net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Error 2 : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza lo que propones también es otra forma interesante de forzar el re-render. @TALABARA, parece que ese es un problema relacionado a los headers, yo esperaría ver en el init object de `fetch` un [/POST/PUT/DELETE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

Comment: además de otros parámetros por ejemplo en los headers `content type`. Trata de seguir el ejemplo de mozilla, espero que puedas avanzar.

Comment: Este ejemplo es de mozilla developer, he usado en otras situaciones el mismo service, pero en esta ocasión se presenta este problema inusual y no encuentro el origen del problema ya que en otros casos no me ha dado ningún problema, pero agradezco la colaboración y la ayuda !!!